# Se puede convertir proyecto Angular2 a Ember?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ember.js, ember-cli

Tengo un proyecto con angular2 y cuando ejecuto el comando

```
ng build -w
```

me aparece un error

> You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the build
> command.

Se puede convertir un proyecto de angular2 existente en un [ember-cli](/questions/tagged/ember-cli) project?

Comment: este stackoverflow es en español

Comment: disculpas, ya lo traduje

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Hola, este no lo pude solucionar, pero empece a utilizar angular-cli (https://cli.angular.io/) para hacer el proyecto con angular2 y me pareció muy simple y cómodo.... saludos